# How do I purchase edges?

Tags: world-of-darkness, hunter-the-reckoning

I'm creating a new character for *Hunter: The Reckoning*. My virtues are Zeal (3 dots). How do I buy my edges?

The short guide on page 84 of the Reckoning book says "edges (according to your Virtue allocation)". I understand this to mean that I have three dots to spend on Zeal edges.

I'm confused about how to spend those dots on edges. Each edge has several ability with a dot cost. Do I pay the full cost of each one? Or are they accumulative?

For example, the Judgment edges (pg.159-162) include:

- Discern (1 dot)
- Burden (2 dots)

If I want both of those, did I just spend 2 dots or 3?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is answered on the bottom of page 129:
"An edge costs its level in virtue points. Thus, a level-one edge costs one point of the appropriate virtue. A level-two edge costs two virtue points."

In the example provided in the question, those two edges would cost 3 virtue points.